# How to delete the previous column count in celltable in gwt?

Tags: gwt

I am getting the previous table column value for the current search. Example: I am searching for a criteria which has four columns in it and it displays fine. When I search for another criteria which has got only 2 columns, it loads the data correctly but it shows some blank space for the other 2 columns(which does not have any data actually). Data grid has the empty space with it.

Comment: Can you please share your piece of code which is causing an issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with some workarounds: https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/6710